# Getting the boundary of a rectangle using the convex hull (in python)

Tags: python, scipy, convex-hull, delaunay

I am trying to get the boundary of a rectangle using `scipy.ConvexHull()`, and it's failing to do so.

```
u=np.linspace(0, 4, 8)
v=np.linspace(5, 10, 8)
u,v=np.meshgrid(u,v)
u=u.flatten()
v=v.flatten()
points2D=np.vstack([u,v]).T


hull = ConvexHull(points2D)
convex_hull_plot_2d(hull)
boundaryList = hull.vertices
print boundaryList
```

gives only the four corners:`[ 0  7 63 56]`

Perturbing the points a bit using the option `qhull_options="QJ Pp"` as follows:

```
 hull = ConvexHull(points2D, qhull_options="QJ Pp")
```

gives more points: `[62 56 40  8  0  2  6  7 15 23 47 55 63]`, but still not the full boundary set.

Can someone tell me a proper fix for this?

Comment: Convex hull is a convex envelope of a set of points that uses the smallest number of points to form that envelope. In this case it is 4 corners of the rectangle. Why and what for do you need all the points on the boundary? I am asking because python's algorithm is perfectly correct in this regard and if you really want all the points then it is probably better if you add it as a postprocessing step.

Comment: The `Delaunary` triangulation gives the full `convex_hull`: `spatial.Delaunay(points2D).convex_hull`.  It's using `qhull` too, but I don't know how the parameters differ.

Comment: @hpaulj it does, am checking it out right now. It is considered inefficient compared to plain hull though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mathematical [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) of convex hull states

> In mathematics, the convex hull or convex envelope of a set X of
>   points in the Euclidean plane or in a Euclidean space (or, more
>   generally, in an affine space over the reals) is the smallest convex
>   set that contains X.

Smallest convex set that contains a rectangle are indeed the four corners that you get.

To get all the points on the boundary you can use the [Delaunay triangulation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.Delaunay.html) and then compute the convex hull from the resulting Delaunay grid,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay

u=np.linspace(0, 4, 8)
v=np.linspace(5, 10, 8)
u,v=np.meshgrid(u,v)
u=u.flatten()
v=v.flatten()
points2D=np.vstack([u,v]).T

tri = Delaunay(points2D)
plt.triplot(points2D[:,0], points2D[:,1], tri.simplices.copy())

boundary = (points2D[tri.convex_hull]).flatten()
bx = boundary[0:-2:2]
by = boundary[1:-1:2]

plt.plot(points2D[:,0], points2D[:,1], 'o')
plt.plot(bx, by, 'rs')

plt.xlim(-1,5)
plt.ylim(4,11)
plt.show()
```

To create the hull after forming the triangulation the program uses [tri.convex_hull](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.Delaunay.convex_hull.html#scipy.spatial.Delaunay.convex_hull). This returns the vertices of facets forming the convex hull for the triangulation points. In your, 2D case, these are lines and the output comes out as a set of neighboring points comprising each line. Note that this approach is considered inefficient as it needs to form the triangulation in addition to convex hull.

The remaining of the program extracts the x and corresponding y values for each point and plots them together with the triangulation resulting in

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Do you understand why the Delaunay `convex_hull` and the default `scipy.spatial.ConvexHull` function so differently?

Comment: Glad to help :) Looking at the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.Delaunay.convex_hull.html), it says that the Delaunay hull are "Vertices of facets forming the convex hull of the point set.". Maybe that is really what it is - list of all facets/lines from the triangulation that coincide with the convex hull of the set/object. I was looking elsewhere too, but this seems like it may be it.